# Criterion for quality of MCMC proposal in a simple discrete setting

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, discrete-distributions

Let's say I have a discrete distribution $p$ over n states that I want to sample from, but I only know a similar probability distribution $q$. However, I can obtain unnormalized probabilities $c \cdot p(i), \ i \in {1, ..., n}$ at a high computational cost. To get approximate samples from $p$ I was considering using MCMC with a state-independent (so non-local) proposal $q$. Is this a good approach? Furthermore, what would be a good criterion to measure the quality of $q$ as a proposal in this context?
I considered $D_{KL}(p||q)$, $D_{KL}(q||p)$ and $D_{JS}(p, q)$ but I'm not sure if there is a good theoretical argument for any of them.

Comment: Since you can compute the unormalised $p$, you can rank $n$ simulations from $q$ to derive the most likely and consider this state as the starting value to the MCMC (with a possible reassessment later if much larger values of $p$ are visited). This means that both $D_{KL}(q||p)$ and $D_{KL}(p||q)$ can be approximated on the run.

Comment: That's true, I could even deterministically check p at the k highest probabilities of q. Evaluating them on the run is a nice idea. However, I'm still not sure which criterion I should evaluate.